# Proof of convergence using comparison test

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Is there a way to prove that these two sequences are divergent using comparison test?

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{∞}1/ln(n!)$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{∞} µ(n)/n^2)$, where  µ(n) is the number of digits of n.

Comment: Do you know ln n!~n ln n ?

Comment: For the first, I'd use [Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to get an upper bound on $\ln{n!}$ (and hence a lower bound on the terms of your series.)

Comment: Isn't $\mu(n)$ just $\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor+1$ (with both in the same base)?

Comment: I got μ(n) is greater or equal to Log(n)

Answer (score 2):

For the first, I suppose you have known the fact that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln (n!)}{n\ln n}=1$$
By comparison test, all we need to show whether $\displaystyle\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ converges or diverges.($k\ge2$) 
Now that $\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ constantly decreases and is always positive. We know 
$$\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\ln x}$$
diverges, so by integral test, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges, and $\sum\limits_{n=k}^{∞}1/\ln(n!)$ diverges. (It should begin at $k\ge2$ not $1$ :)
For the second question, @Regret 's comment reveals everything, just note that when $n$ is very large
$$0<μ(n)=⌊\log(n)⌋+1<\sqrt n$$
Thus 
$$0<µ(n)/n^2<\frac{1}{n^{\frac32}}$$
Because $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{1}{n^{\frac32}}$ converges, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{∞} µ(n)/n^2$ converges.